# css media query not being loaded sometimes in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding this media query css to a div in a site:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

    .left-panel-container {
        width: 240px;
    }
```

And it works, but sometimes (randomly) after refreshing the page, it doesn't apply the media query even though I see it's in the loaded css file.
This works fine in Chrome, Firefox but it only bugs in IE.

Any hint? Is this a known issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have other media queries that are using `max-width`?

Comment: For that particular div? no. Only this min-width.

Comment: @msqar What do you see when it does work, and when it does not?

Comment: When it does work, the left container would have a width of 240px, when it doesn't work, since it's not loading the media query, the container has a 100% width

Comment: Well, the problem is not with the css you provide, you will need to be more specific on your question, add more code and possibly a fiddle that displays the issue.

Comment: For trouble shooting purposes add `width: 240px !important;`

Comment: left panel has a default width of 100%. That's why it's 100% width when media query isn't loaded. I will try to create a jsfiddle and see if i can re-create the issue in IE. Hold on

Comment: @msqar Do you have screenshots? Or a link to an active page?

Comment: Looks like i couldn't reproduce it on a jsfiddle, it might be something on my page. I will solve it by triggering a window resize, that seems to fix it. Don't know why IE is bugging with this. But thanks for the replies guys.